# Xpages Getting Select 2 to work with current Extension Library

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

I have installed the latest Extension Library and am building an Xpages app with Bootstrap. Select 2 is not included in the current Ext Lib. It is included in Xpages4Bootstrap. While that is an excellent extension I am not sure if I really should include that just to get Select2 - unless there are other benefits. But how do I install Select 2 so it works with the Extension Library? I tried using the steps from [this post](http://xpagesandmore.blogspot.com/2014/09/using-select2-in-xpages.html) but so far no luck. When I run the code I get

```
'JQuery' not found at [/select2.min.js.jss]
```

Comment: The answers below are correct if you want to use v4 of Select2. But that version still has quite some issues. For now I'd recommend to download the latest v3 release. That version is very stable and doesn't use AMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could had be an AMD loading problem. When I look at Github github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/dist/js/select2.js I see an AMD check at the beginning of the code. Just remove the AMD if then else and keep the latest else clause or change define.AMD by false