# Looking for a sample db using select2

Tags: xpages

I have been trying to get select2 to work on an existing xPages application with no luck.  I keep getting errors saying select2() is not a function.  I must have something messed up with my files/folders for the required code.

I am not sure what files I need to incorporate into the Web-Inf folder.  I am using Domino 9.0.1 FP3

Does anyone have a sample db I could get to pick apart and see what I am missing?

Comment: Your terms to google for: select2 AMD Xpages. The problem is that select2 uses AMD which won't work with XPages unless you tweak it a bit. We recently had this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183917/xpages-getting-select-2-to-work-with-current-extension-library

Comment: I have tried that post.  I think it's something I am doing wrong with the files I downloaded, the folders and how I load them in the theme.  I was hoping to find a sample db that it's working on so I can duplicate it in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the Select2 demo on [Bootstrap4XPages.com](http://bootstrap4xpages.com). That site is powered using the Bootstrap version in the ExtLib and no longer relies on the Bootstrap4XPages plugin. Select2 was added to the demo database in the **WebContent** folder and is loaded through a theme.

I've created the following examples:

- Enabling Select2 on a **ComboBox** control, including a handler for the 'onchange' event that refreshes another section of the page.
- Enabling Select2 on a **ListBox** control with multi-select.
- A Select2 field that is attached to a (hidden) input and uses **Ajax to get JSON search results** from a second XPage.

Good luck picking it apart :-) The source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/markleusink/Bootstrap4XPages/tree/master/Demos)