# MultipleDefine xspClientDojo.js and dojo.js error

Tags: dojo, xpages

I having a problem with MultipleDefine xspClientDojo and dojo.

I have implemented select2 version 4.0.3 in a xPage theme.
But I get an error in the browser console, when loading the page.

The select2 fields are working, but some other dojo things are not.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens and how to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simular problem here [Xpages Getting Select 2 to work with current Extension Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183917/xpages-getting-select-2-to-work-with-current-extension-library)

And the solution was to outcomment the AMD part in the start of the select2.js file.

Comment: In case you don't want to change the select2.js use this snippet: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=hack-to-use-jquery-amd-widgets-and-dojo-together

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with "select2 version 4.0.3 theme", but multi-define error is usually the result of conflict of having more than one widget with the same id.

Comment: the select2 is just loaded by an xPage theme. It is not a specific select2-theme.